# how to retrieve foreign key from another table if i fetch its giving me all the primary ids instead

Tags: php, sql

What i want to achieve is to fetch rows based on the foreign key if i select from Table B all the rows with the same fk in the table should be displayed
This is table tbl_invoice_items
[image]
This is table tbl_invoice_total
[image]
The problem is am failing to limit fk based when am fetching using INNER JOIN not sure where the problem is
[image]

```
public function getAllInvoice($invoice_fk){
    $this->db->query("SELECT tbl_invoice_items.*, tbl_invoice_total.*,tbl_invoice_total.invoices_id FROM tbl_invoice_items
    INNER JOIN tbl_invoice_total
    ON tbl_invoice_items.invoice_fk = tbl_invoice_total.invoices_id
    WHERE tbl_invoice_items.invoice_fk = :invoice_fk");
    $this->db->bind(':invoice_fk',$invoice_fk);
    $results = $this->db->resultSet();
    return $results;
```

}

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected result, and current result. It's hard to do sql questions without data

Comment: There are no table A or table B in your code example, do A and B represent table names from your example? You actually retrieve all columns (= fields) from both tables in your example. What more is there to retrieve?

Comment: Yes A and B represents table names where table a has a primary key invoices_id and table be as a foreign key invoice_fk the problem is when i fetch data from table B its getting all the data from there i want it to get only data with the same foreign key number which is a primary key in table A

Comment: Well, that's what an [INNER JOIN](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-inner-join.aspx) does. It's unclear to me what exactly you want to do.

Comment: What i want to do is to fetch only data with the same foreign key

Comment: "same foreign key"...same as what? Please be clear and specific. [edit] your question when you have relevant information to share, including what I mentioned in my first comment. It's a _lot_ easier to help with a SQL issue if you share samples of the relevant data.

Comment: `which i dont want`...so what result _do_ you want then? Please provide a sample of the expected result too, as previously requested. Your query simply selects all the rows from both the tables. Are you trying to ask how to display the results only for one specific customer maybe? Or for one specific invoice? It sounds like you want to restrict the results in some way, but you have not described clearly what restriction should be applied. In any case, if  you want to restrict results in a SQL query, then as you will know from basic SQL training, this requires a `WHERE` clause in the query.

Comment: Yes i want to restrict selection based on foreign key to view invoice data details for a specifc customer

Comment: Ok. So then you simply need to add something like `WHERE tbl_invoice_items.invoice_fk = 59`, or whatever. That has nothing to do with the `JOIN`. Knowing to restrict the results using `WHERE` is very basic SQL knowledge - have you done some introductory SQL training?

Comment: Sorry, I voted to close this question a long time ago, and didn't retract that vote when you updated it. Now I have, but now it requires more reopen votes for the question to be opened again. However, I do think that ADyson has already solved your problem. Did you get it working the way you wanted?

Comment: if i use where it was giving me an error not sure where i am going wrong

Comment: Well if  you want help with that, you'll need to [edit] your question to  show us what you tried, and what error it produces! Obviously we cannot really just guess what the issue is!

Comment: WHERE tbl_invoice_items.invoice_fk = 59 is showing yes but is i place a placeholder its saying syntax to use near ':invoice_fk ' at line 1

Comment: 1) please [edit] your question as requested, instead burying important info in the comments where it does not belong. 2) don't give us only half the code. 3) don't give us only half an error message. Details can be important. If you give us vague or incomplete information it only makes it more difficult for us to help you. We cannot see your screen.

Comment: Please try to be a clear as possible. That means showing the whole query and the whole error message, as they are. We can't see what you see.

Comment: Sure let me edit the questions then

Comment: Okay it has worked Just like  ADyson had put it now i need to reference that key to the primary key and  i 
was not passing the value from the other page when i say where clause thanks a lot for you help